# Save Crop image in php

Tags: php, image

I crop image using `imagecopy`  in php. but I want save it to my old path. what can I used for it ? this is my method how i crop the image .

```
$w=250;
    $h=300;    
    $x=$_POST['x1'];    
    $y=$_POST['y1'];   
    $filename="upload/".$_SESSION['basename'];
    header('Content-type: image/jpg');
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$src);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    $crop = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
    $new = imagecopy ($crop, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h);
    imagejpeg($crop);
    imagedestroy($filename);
```

I used this method, but it was not work for me.

```
$input = 'upload/'.$new;
    $output = 'upload/xxx.jpg';
    file_put_contents($output, file_get_contents($input));
```

Comment: Please can you define "not working". Is the file created? Are there any errors? Do you have permissions to write to that path?

Comment: yes.. I have permissions to write. It was created xxx.jpg. but when I open that image it said "windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged corrupted".

Answer (score 3):

Just specify where you want it to save the file

```
imagejpeg($crop,$FILENAME);
```

### EDIT

Based on your comment below, the problem is not saving the file , it is that you do not have a valid image resource to begin with.

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

should be

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
if (!$image)
    exit("not a valid image");
```

You are telling it to copy $x,$y to 250,300 from the orignal image into the new image, but there has been no check to ensure that you have an image that is big enough to do that, or indeed that x and y exist or that they are less than 250,300

Also you care currently trying to `imagedestroy()` a filename. You can only imagedestroy an image resource.

```
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($crop);
```

Comment: Thanks Anigel I did it. but it wasn't work. this is my code.
$new2 = "new/".$_SESSION['basename'];
imagejpeg($crop,$new2);
imagedestroy($filename);------------ it said "The image "http://localhost/xxx/crop.php" cannot be displayed because it contains error."